# Getting "SpringBoard was unable to service the request" error on Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

When I build the app on simulator in Xcode 8.0, I am getting "**SpringBoard was unable to service the request**" error.

Please let me know how to resolve this error of Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Quit the Simulator and press Cmd+R on Xcode

Comment: You should restart Xcode and Simulator either if you have older simulators opened, you should close them.

Answer (score 23):

Force quit the simulator and Xcode really works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Worked solution :
    i) Close the simulator
    ii)Clean the Xcode cmd+shift+k
    iii)Preference =>Derived Data => Move to trash 
    iv) Close Xcode
    v) Clean Trash
    iii)Relaunch Xcode

Comment: In my case, after closing both of Xcode and Simulator, it worked.

Comment: If above error reoccur then I will  give a shot to your steps. (y) . Anyway we can accept above answer.

Answer (score 3):

1.Quit the simulator

2.Cmd+shift+k(clean)the Code

3.Run again application.

Answer (score 2):

Quitting the simulator and clearing the derived data worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please close simulator and run again. if this doesn't work for you then try again after reset simulator.

This worked for me.